# Match element N with certain name with element N of other XML when XSL merging

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, merge

I have two XML documents I need to merge.

```
<!-- A.xml -->
<cm:Process>
    <cm:Other />
    <cm:Elements />
    <cm:Request>
        <!-- stuff -->
    </cm:Request>
    <cm:ElementCouldBeHereToo />
    <cm:Request>
        <!-- stuff -->
    </cm:Request>
</cm:Process>

<!-- B.xml -->
<gateway-orders>
    <response>
        <status />
    </response>
    <response>
        <status />
    </response>
</gateway-orders>
```

The first is the original XML. The requests has been pulled out and sent to a system and the next is the responses. Now I need to merge these two and match request N with response N so I can pull in some info from the responses. The XSL work on A.xml and get B.xml as a parameter. To begin with I'm just trying to create a copy of the correct response in B.xml inside the request in A.xml.

The problem I have is that I thought I could use `position()`, but realized that won't work since the `cm:Request` elements are mixed with other elements. Is there another way I can use to match up these somehow?

This is what I tried:

```
<xsl:import href="identity-transform.xsl" />

<xsl:param name="responses" />


<xsl:template match="cm:Request">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$responses/*[1]/*[position()]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

There are two problems here.

1. First of all the `position()` won't match up. Is there a way to get the number/position of `cm:Request` elements you're at rather than the number/position of all sibling elements? So that the first `cm:Request` always gives 1 irregardless of if it has any elements in front of it.
2. Secondly I for some reason get a copy of *all* responses inside each request. If I change `position()` with for example `1`, I only get a copy of the first response in each request. What am I doing wrong here?

Hoping someone knows what I should do here, cause I'm a bit blank right now and my Google-fu is failing me :P

**So to sum up**, how can I match up the nth element with name `blah` with the nth child in a parameter node-set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:template match="cm:Request">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        <xsl:variable name="reqNum" select="count(preceding-sibling::cm:Request | .)" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$responses/*[1]/response[$reqNum]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To explain this:

> > 2.Secondly I for some reason get a copy of all responses inside each request. If I change position() with for example 1, I only get a copy of the first response in each request. What am I doing wrong here?

In this case, `position()` is actually behaving differently from how you think it is.  If you did this in that template:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
```

*Then* `$pos` would have the position of the current `cm:Request` in relation to all of its siblings, but here:

```
$responses/*[1]/*[position()]
```

`position()` is being evaluated in the context `$responses/*[1]/*`.  So for the first `<response>` this evaluates to `$responses/*[1]/*[1]` and for the second response, this evaluates to `$responses/*[1]/*[2]`, hence both are always selected.

Comment: Interesting. Both yours and the answer of @martin-honnen seems to give the same result. What's the difference between them? Seems to be more exact, but not sure what `<xsl:number/>` gives exactly (other than that it appears to return the same in this case).

Comment: @Svish [From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number): _If count attribute is not specified, then it defaults to the pattern that matches any node with the same node type as the current node and, if the current node has an expanded-name, with the same expanded-name as the current node._ In other words, when `<xsl:number>` is used with no attributes, it produces the number of preceding siblings with the same name and namespace as the current node, +1.

Comment: @Svish In other words, Martin's example and mine do practically the exact same thing in two different ways. I think his approach is pretty nifty and it's something I hadn't known about before, though mine has the benefit of being pretty clear what it does without knowing the ins-and-outs of `<xsl:number>`. So I think which one to use is just a matter of preference.

Comment: That's pretty nifty indeed! Think I'll go for the shorter version, but I'll accept yours since you explained the other issue as well :)

Answer (score 1):

One way should be

```
<xsl:template match="cm:Request">
  <xsl:variable name="index"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$responses/*[1]/*[position() = $index]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What does `<xsl:number/>` do exactly in this case? It seems to give the correct result, but not sure why :p

Comment: @JLRishe figured it out. Thanks!